# Read socket data byte by byte and return as a string

Tags: python, sockets

I need to read data from socket byte by byte. I try to do with this code:

```
lineF = ''
for DataByte in client[0].recv(1):
    lineF += DataByte
```

result `lineF` must be an data string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What type of object is `client[0]`? Assuming it is a `socket` object from the standard library, then `recv()` already gives you a bytestring. If you want it as a text string, you would use the `.decode()` with whatever encoding whoever is sending you the data is using - eg,

```
 data = client[0].recv(1).decode('utf-8')
```

EDIT: in the case that, per your comment below, you don't know the length of the stream in advance, you need to keep reading until the data comes back empty. The built-in `iter()` helps with this:

```
 def read_socket():
      return client[0].recv(1)

 data = b''.join(iter(read_socket, b''))
```

Also, if this is the only reason for reading a byte at a time - you can, and probably should, use a larger buffer size. If there's fewer bytes in the stream than the buffer can hold, it will just give you those bytes.

Comment: Yes. recv() gives me a bytestring. I can get whole string using client[0].recv(1024) but i don't khow string length. It may be various. I need to get all data byte by byte and then get a bytestring.